# Trying to get Composer to bring a folder 'src/' from it's package over with it to a my project

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, composer-php

I built a little library to test how I can use Composer to build libraries and bring then across into my projects when ever. I can inject the library fine but it doesn't seem to bring across my folder 'src/' which hold classes. I want Composer to bring this folder along with the rest of the library so I can use it. I have tried working around with the composer.json file using psr-4, classmap etc but must be doing it wrong.

My files and folder structure are below.

Library composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "icbfdblibs/ipmanager",
"description": "IPManager library",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "zf2"
],
"homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "~2.4"
},

"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "IPManager\\": "src/"
    }
},
"classmap": [
    "src/"
]

}
```

How the folder structure for the library is:

```
MainFolder
  |
  ---ipmanager
        |
        ---src
            |
            ---IPManager
                |
                ---IPManager.php
        ---build.xml
        ---composer.json
        ---etc.etc
```

The project I'm using to bring the above library across composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
"description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "zf2"
],
"homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.0",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "~2.4",
    "icbfdblibs/welcomelib": "1.0.7",
    "icbfdblibs/ipmanager": "1.0.8"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "test\\test\\public\\": "" }
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"repositories": [
{
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "icbfdblibs/ipmanager",
            "version": "1.0.8",
            "dist": {
                "url": "/home/{username}/dev/git/{name}libs/ipmanager/application.zpk",
                "type": "zip"
            }
    }
}
]
}
```

I get the library with the above configuration but not the src file which I want.

Any help or guidance would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what's your question - what's the problem/error? can you be more clear about?

Comment: I'm trying to bring to folder 'src' across with the library like the rest of the folders in the library. But it doesn't come across at all. So when I use composer update I get everything but the src. I don't know how I would bring it across.